# JS script for npm-start

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-start

I would like to know if we can write/pass the `npm-start` command as a JS script.

**Requirement: Create a JS script that can execute the command `npm-start`.**

OS: Microsoft Windows

---

My requirement is to convert it to a Windows service. However, for the below code under script I cannot directly pass `npm-start`.

```js
var Service = require('node-windows').Service;

// Create a new service object
var svc = new Service({
  name:'npm-start',
  description: 'start npm',
  script: 'pass npm-start command as a script.js'
});

svc.on('install', function(){
  svc.start();
});

svc.install();
```

Comment: Please add your code that you have tried so that we can correct you, instead of giving you code. **This question may lead to opinions.**

Comment: hi,

below is the code. my requirement is to covert it to a windows service. however for below code under script i cannot directly pass 'npm-start'



`var Service = require('node-windows').Service;

// Create a new service object
var svc = new Service({
  name:'npm-start',
  description: 'start npm',
  script: 'js script to pass npm-start.js'
});

svc.on('install',function(){
  svc.start();
});

svc.install();`

Comment: Did *Joe105598055*'s question help you?

Comment: @ArnavThorat im taking a look at that still. But im still open for suggestions and help on this. This is something new for me.

Comment: Okay, cool! I'm big on coding and the Windows operating system, but not sure how to solve your question. I'm still working it out though!

Answer (score -1):

Try it. If you want to create command line interface.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/commander